# MuPDF 1.7 & 1.8 save error in Android with error "libc(11538): heap corruption detected by dlmalloc"

Tags: android, mupdf

I was using MuPDF 1.6 and everything was running smoothly. Recently I am trying to upgrade my project to MuPDF 1.8. Everything runs as expected except when I try to save when annotations are added to the PDF files. I tried different sized PDF files but everytimes on Save it says "Unfortunately, MuPDF has stopped," and returns to file selection menu. I am using Kitkat(4.4.2), then I tried to use 4.2.2, it didnt give the error message but I found that the PDF file has not saved. Although it was working fine from MuPDF 1.2 to 1.6. Then I have installed MuPDF 1.8 from google play and it is giving same error message:"Unfortunately, MuPDF has stopped," when I add annotation and press back button and on the dialog "Document has changes, Save them?" Yes is chosen. I searched and surprised to find that no one reported similar problem even when Play store apk has the same issue.

Main error:

```
12-08 22:25:05.726: A/libc(11538): heap corruption detected by dlmalloc
12-08 22:25:05.726: A/libc(11538): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002d12 (code=-6), thread 11538 (tifex.mupdfdemo)
12-08 22:25:19.741: D/AbsListView(12047): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-08 22:25:19.826: D/libEGL(12047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-08 22:25:19.826: D/libEGL(12047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-08 22:25:19.831: D/libEGL(12047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-08 22:25:19.836: E/(12047): Device driver API match
12-08 22:25:19.836: E/(12047): Device driver API version: 23
12-08 22:25:19.836: E/(12047): User space API version: 23 
12-08 22:25:19.836: E/(12047): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014
```

Below is the log data:

```
12-08 22:24:49.446: I/System.out(11538): URI to open is: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Final/fiqr.pdf
12-08 22:24:49.446: I/System.out(11538): Trying to open /storage/emulated/0/Download/Final/fiqr.pdf
12-08 22:24:49.471: D/dalvikvm(11538): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.artifex.mupdfdemo-2/libmupdf.so 0x4203e520
12-08 22:24:49.501: D/dalvikvm(11538): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.artifex.mupdfdemo-2/libmupdf.so 0x4203e520
12-08 22:24:49.501: D/dalvikvm(11538): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.artifex.mupdfdemo-2/libmupdf.so 0x4203e520, skipping init
12-08 22:24:49.511: I/libmupdf(11538): Opening document...
12-08 22:24:49.551: I/alert(11538): alert_init
12-08 22:24:49.551: I/libmupdf(11538): Done!
12-08 22:24:49.726: D/ProgressBar(11538): setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 0
12-08 22:24:49.736: D/AbsSeekBar(11538): AbsSeekBar Constructor: misSeebarAnimationAvailable = false
12-08 22:24:49.781: I/alert(11538): Enter startAlerts
12-08 22:24:49.781: I/alert(11538): Exit startAlerts
12-08 22:24:49.791: I/alert(11538): Enter waitForAlert
12-08 22:24:50.021: I/dalvikvm-heap(11538): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.468MB for 4096016-byte allocation
12-08 22:24:50.036: I/dalvikvm-heap(11538): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.379MB for 4096016-byte allocation
12-08 22:24:50.071: D/dalvikvm(11538): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 306K, 8% free 15498K/16780K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
12-08 22:24:50.126: I/libmupdf(11538): Drop page 0
12-08 22:24:50.126: I/libmupdf(11538): Goto page 0...
12-08 22:24:50.126: I/libmupdf(11538): Load page 0
12-08 22:24:50.126: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
12-08 22:24:50.126: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
12-08 22:24:50.126: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: right = 64
12-08 22:24:50.126: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 64
12-08 22:24:50.126: I/libmupdf(11538): PageWidth=1191
12-08 22:24:50.126: I/libmupdf(11538): PageHeight=1685
12-08 22:24:50.141: D/dalvikvm(11538): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 60K, 8% free 15545K/16780K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
12-08 22:24:50.151: I/dalvikvm-heap(11538): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.032MB for 4096016-byte allocation
12-08 22:24:50.166: D/dalvikvm(11538): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 19542K/20784K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: right = 64
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 64
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: right = 758
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 37
12-08 22:24:50.181: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: mProgressDrawable.setBounds()
12-08 22:24:50.196: I/libmupdf(11538): Drop page 0
12-08 22:24:50.196: I/libmupdf(11538): Goto page 1...
12-08 22:24:50.196: I/libmupdf(11538): Load page 1
12-08 22:24:50.196: I/libmupdf(11538): PageWidth=1191
12-08 22:24:50.196: I/libmupdf(11538): PageHeight=1685
12-08 22:24:50.351: I/libmupdf(11538): PageWidth=1191
12-08 22:24:50.351: I/libmupdf(11538): PageHeight=1685
12-08 22:24:50.351: I/libmupdf(11538): In native method
12-08 22:24:50.351: I/libmupdf(11538): Checking format
12-08 22:24:50.351: I/libmupdf(11538): locking pixels
12-08 22:24:50.351: I/libmupdf(11538): Rendering page(0)=800x1131 patch=[0,0,800,1131]
12-08 22:24:50.696: I/libmupdf(11538): Rendered
12-08 22:24:50.696: I/libmupdf(11538): PageWidth=1191
12-08 22:24:50.701: I/libmupdf(11538): PageHeight=1685
12-08 22:24:50.701: I/libmupdf(11538): In native method
12-08 22:24:50.701: I/libmupdf(11538): Checking format
12-08 22:24:50.701: I/libmupdf(11538): locking pixels
12-08 22:24:50.701: I/libmupdf(11538): Rendering page(1)=800x1131 patch=[0,0,800,1131]
12-08 22:24:50.851: I/libmupdf(11538): Rendered
12-08 22:24:52.951: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
12-08 22:24:52.951: I/libmupdf(11538): Drop page 0
12-08 22:24:52.951: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
12-08 22:24:52.951: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: right = 64
12-08 22:24:52.951: D/ProgressBar(11538): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 64
12-08 22:24:52.951: I/libmupdf(11538): Goto page 2...
12-08 22:24:52.951: I/libmupdf(11538): Load page 2
12-08 22:24:52.951: I/libmupdf(11538): PageWidth=1191
12-08 22:24:52.951: I/libmupdf(11538): PageHeight=1685
12-08 22:24:52.991: I/libmupdf(11538): PageWidth=1191
12-08 22:24:52.991: I/libmupdf(11538): PageHeight=1685
12-08 22:24:52.991: I/libmupdf(11538): In native method
12-08 22:24:52.991: I/libmupdf(11538): Checking format
12-08 22:24:52.991: I/libmupdf(11538): locking pixels
12-08 22:24:52.991: I/libmupdf(11538): Rendering page(2)=800x1131 patch=[0,0,800,1131]
12-08 22:24:53.366: I/libmupdf(11538): Rendered
12-08 22:24:56.271: I/libmupdf(11538): PageWidth=1191
12-08 22:24:56.271: I/libmupdf(11538): PageHeight=1685
12-08 22:24:57.861: I/libmupdf(11538): PageWidth=1191
12-08 22:24:57.861: I/libmupdf(11538): PageHeight=1685
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): In native method
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): Checking format
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): locking pixels
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): Rendering page(1)=800x1131 patch=[0,0,800,1131]
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): Start partial update
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): Update rectangle (123, 364, 676, 464)
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): And it isn't empty
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): End partial update
12-08 22:24:58.036: I/libmupdf(11538): Rendered
12-08 22:25:01.971: E/ViewRootImpl(11538): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12-08 22:25:05.726: A/libc(11538): heap corruption detected by dlmalloc
12-08 22:25:05.726: A/libc(11538): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002d12 (code=-6), thread 11538 (tifex.mupdfdemo)
12-08 22:25:19.741: D/AbsListView(12047): Get MotionRecognitionManager
12-08 22:25:19.826: D/libEGL(12047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-08 22:25:19.826: D/libEGL(12047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-08 22:25:19.831: D/libEGL(12047): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-08 22:25:19.836: E/(12047): Device driver API match
12-08 22:25:19.836: E/(12047): Device driver API version: 23
12-08 22:25:19.836: E/(12047): User space API version: 23 
12-08 22:25:19.836: E/(12047): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Fri Mar 21 13:52:50 KST 2014
```

Comment: The problem may be specific to the PDF file you are trying to annotate - can you upload it somewhere and edit your question to add a link to the problem file?

Comment: Seems unlikely, because I tried with many pdf file with same result and same pdf works with MuPDF1.6 and MuPDF1.2.